# What functionalities can be put in the presenter for the MVP Design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I have been using MVP for a while .Sometimes I get confused what actions can be performed inside the presenter.
For me, I have a presenter only serves as layer to talk to the service layer(data access and other utility class) and update the view.
Can anyone share some thought on what actions can be performed in the presenter and what can not be? Some useful links on that would be good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to provide a list of links for you as they would explain this better than I could.

- http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2008/02/26/model-view-presenter-variations-on-the-basic-pattern-introduction-to-cabscsf-part-24/
- http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=070203
- http://www.pnpguidance.net/Tag/ModelViewPresenter.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Also read up on what Martin Fowler has to say about it:

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html (Passive View, Supervising Controller)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a blog entry on the MVP (Model View Presenter) - Passive View pattern. Take a look at it and see what you think.

http://coding.infoconex.com/post/(MVP)-Model-View-Presenter-Passive-View.aspx

Comment: I read your blog , generally it is very good.But I put some of my thought in the comments.